# Can I use jquery to alternate the color of these fonts?

Tags: jquery

I am using this function to change the font-size on the class "tag-link," which is numbered like

"tag-link-1" "tag-link-2" etc.

So that's why it's using `^`

```
 $(function () {
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('fontSize', '1em');
    });
```

What I would like to do, however, is also make this function change the font-color of every other tag. Right now, the font-color is blue, but I want it to alternative blue and red for example. It will make the fonts easier to read if they're not all the same color side by side.

Do you know how to alter this function to make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(function () {
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('fontSize', '1em');
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]:odd').css('color', '#FF0000');
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]:even').css('color', '#00FF00');
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]').css({
                                'fontSize':'1em',
                                'color':'#FF0000'
    });
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]:even').css('color', '#00FF00');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

U can use :even or :odd selectors

```
$(function () {
    $('a[class^="tag-link"]:even').css('color', '#ff0000');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an appropriate manual page: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/